# Taking string in 8086 Assembly and counting a characters in it

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

I'm currently trying to write a code in assembly for taking some string from user and calculate the 'a' characters in it. The job seems very simple but the problem is I can't really count properly and don't know what is the problem. For example for the word 'amin', the output is 97, or for others something like >6. And there is not many tutorials in internet for assembly 8086. So if anyone can help I'll be thankful.

```
stk     segment
    dw 32 dup(?)
stk     ends

dts     segment
    p1 db 10,13,'Please enter max 80 char',10,13,'$'
    p2 db 10,13,'Number of (a) chars:  $'
    max db 80
    len db ?
    count db 0
    char db 'a'
    str db 80 dup (?)
dts ends

cds     segment
    assume cs:cds, ss:stk, ds:dts
    main proc far
        mov ax, seg dts
        mov ds,ax
        mov ah,09
        mov dx,offset p1
        int 21h

        mov ah,0ah
        mov dx,offset max
        int 21h

        lea si,str
        mov cl,len
        mov ch,0 ; Initializing CX(Counter) Register for loop
check:
        mov al,[si]
        cmp char,al
        jne skip
        inc count
skip:
        inc si; Next char in str
        loop check

        mov al,count
        mov ah,0
        mov dl,10
        div dl
        add ax,3030h; making the right ascii code for printing
        mov bx,offset max-3
        mov [bx],ax
        mov ah,09
        mov dx,offset p2
        int 21h

        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h

    main endp
cds ends

    end main
```

Comment: *"And there is not many tutorials in internet for assembly 8086."* really? Are you in China behind the great firewall? I can agree if you would say "not many **excellent** tutorials", that's rare, but actually for x86 you can find ton of the stuff, it even has dedicated SW project "emu8086" for lecturing students (but better stay away from that emulator, if you can, it's not of high quality) ... Just searching through stack overflow tag [x86-16] should lead you to many working examples in answers (and many common mistakes/pitfalls in questions) - click on the tag under your Q and check some..

Comment: about your code ... the service [`int 21h, 0a`](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-a.html) to enter the string from user requires different structure of memory buffer, your definition of `count` and `char` are in place of the first and second byte of the actual buffer for input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

int 21h,ah=0ah reads user input into the buffer at DS:DX. The first byte of the buffer pointed to by DS:DX is the maximum length, followed by the actual length, followed by the characters read. You need to define `str` immediately following len; otherwise the input overwrites `count` and `char`. The reason you get 97 is that `count` is overwritten by the first character of your input.

To make this clearer in your code, I suggest writing it like this:

```
buf:
    max db 80
    len db ?
    str db 80 dup (?)

count db 0
char db 'a'
```

Then before the int 21h,ah=0ah,

```
    mov dx, offset buf
```